# Expression tree: variable referenced but not defined

Tags: c#, expression

I am building an expression to dynamically build some code for efficient manual JSON serialization for my model objects without having to update it anytime I change the models. My expression is throwing the following exception below.

Do I need an expression to first declare the variable before assigning it or something?

**System.InvalidOperationException: 'variable 'sw' of type 'System.IO.StringWriter' referenced from scope '', but it is not defined'**

```
public static Func<T, string> ConstructJsonParserFunction<T>()
    {
        List<Expression> methodBodyExpressions = new List<Expression>();
        ParameterExpression methodParameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "entity");
        ParameterExpression stringWriterExpression = Expression.Variable(typeof(StringWriter), "sw");
        ParameterExpression jsonTextWriterExpression = Expression.Variable(typeof(JsonTextWriter), "writer");
        ConstructorInfo jsonTextWriterConstructor = typeof(JsonTextWriter).GetConstructor(new Type[] { typeof(TextWriter) });
        MethodInfo jsonTextWriterMethod_WriteStartObject = typeof(JsonTextWriter).GetMethod("WriteStartObject");
        MethodInfo jsonTextWriterMethod_WritePropertyName = typeof(JsonTextWriter).GetMethods()
            .Where(mi => mi.Name == "WritePropertyName" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 1 && mi.GetParameters()[0].Name == "name")
            .First();

        Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo> jsonTextWriterMethods_WriteValue = new Dictionary<Type, MethodInfo>();

        foreach (MethodInfo method in typeof(JsonTextWriter).GetMethods().Where(mi => mi.Name == "WriteValue" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 1))
        {
            jsonTextWriterMethods_WriteValue[method.GetParameters()[0].ParameterType] = method;
        }

        MethodInfo jsonTextWriterMethod_WriteEndObject = typeof(JsonTextWriter).GetMethod("WriteEndObject");
        MethodInfo stringWriterMethod_ToString = typeof(StringWriter).GetMethods()
            .Where(mi => mi.Name == "ToString" && mi.GetParameters().Length == 0)
            .First();

        methodBodyExpressions.Add(stringWriterExpression);
        methodBodyExpressions.Add(jsonTextWriterExpression);
        methodBodyExpressions.Add(Expression.Assign(stringWriterExpression, Expression.New(typeof(StringWriter))));
        methodBodyExpressions.Add(Expression.Assign(jsonTextWriterExpression, Expression.New(jsonTextWriterConstructor, stringWriterExpression)));
        methodBodyExpressions.Add(Expression.Call(jsonTextWriterExpression, jsonTextWriterMethod_WriteStartObject));

        foreach (PropertyInfo property in typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(p => Attribute.IsDefined(p, typeof(JsonPropertyAttribute))))
        {
            methodBodyExpressions.Add(Expression.Call(jsonTextWriterExpression, jsonTextWriterMethod_WritePropertyName, Expression.Constant(property.Name)));
            methodBodyExpressions.Add(Expression.Call(jsonTextWriterExpression, jsonTextWriterMethods_WriteValue[property.PropertyType], Expression.Property(methodParameter, property)));
        }

        methodBodyExpressions.Add(Expression.Call(jsonTextWriterExpression, jsonTextWriterMethod_WriteEndObject));
        methodBodyExpressions.Add(Expression.Call(stringWriterExpression, stringWriterMethod_ToString));

        BlockExpression block = Expression.Block(methodBodyExpressions);

        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(block, methodParameter).Compile();
    }
```

The debug view string:

```
.Block() {
    $sw;
    $writer;
    $sw = .New System.IO.StringWriter();
    $writer = .New Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextWriter($sw);
    .Call $writer.WriteStartObject();
    .Call $writer.WritePropertyName("CompanyId");
    .Call $writer.WriteValue($entity.CompanyId);
    .Call $writer.WritePropertyName("Name");
    .Call $writer.WriteValue($entity.Name);
    .Call $writer.WriteEndObject();
    .Call $sw.ToString()
}
```

**EDIT**

Solution: As stated by NetMage, local variables require two things before they can be assigned. First, use `Expression.Variable(type, "debugVarName")` to create ParameterExpression. Second, the `Expression.Block` should pass ParameterExpressions separately from the body.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created an sw parameter `stringWriterExpression` (should have called it `stringWriterParameter`) and you used it in your body, but you didn't define is as a lambda parameter.

I think you need to use `Expression.Variable` instead of `Expression.Parameter` and added it as a `ParameterExpression[]` to your Block.